# Regex for PS Script to read form a line

Tags: regex, powershell

Regex from a line where I want specific things to be extracted. Example: In the line I have: This is a test 2016/01/23 This is test 04:05 AM this is a test Success Login at 01.33 sec. How can I extract only the date, time & success time. So output would be

---

(2016/01/23 04:05 AM Success 01.33 sec).

Appreciate your help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect I'm going to answer, and then you're going to comment *"my real data is completely different how do I match that?"*. Let's see.

```
# Here is your log line
$logLine = 'This is a test 2016/01/23 This is test 04:05 AM this is a test  Success Login at 01.33 sec'

# Here is my regex which matches
#           *    date          *    time    AMPM * Success Login      time       *
$myRegex = '.*(\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d).*(\d\d:\d\d \S\S).*Success Login at ([0-9.]+ \S+).*'

# Here is the test and output building
if ($logLine -match $myRegex) { 
    Write-Host "($($matches[1]) $($matches[2]) Success $($matches[3]))"
} else {
    Write-Host "Log doesn't match"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Only thing. when I have next line Fail it still shows Success. How can I sort by fail/success? I appreciate your input.

Comment: @SamTam What do you mean? What does the next line look like? What do you want to sort?